# Using mysql image from docker

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

I am trying to use the available mysql tags from [this doc](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

I am using the following command to download the image

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

But when I run this image with

```
sudo docker run mysql:tag
```

it gives the following error

```
error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set
Did you forget to add -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=... ?
```

Any idea on where else to set this password?

Comment: I copied/pasted your docker command and other than having to change `tag` to be a version of MySQL it worked just fine as it is. Have you tried using `-d mysql:5.6.24`?

Comment: Just tried and gives the same error

Comment: Are using the whole command `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:<version>` and not just `sudo docker run mysql:tag`?

Comment: You're already running the image -- `docker run` runs an image. If you had wanted to just download it and not run it you would have needed to use another command. Or to put it another way, the first command ran the image, then when you did `sudo docker run mysql:tag` you were trying to run another copy of the same image (but without the necessary parameters, hence the error),

Comment: If you want to download image, you can use docker pull command. https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#pull